# Access to this directory is denied

Tags: c#

I have discovered a problem with using a StreamReader to read a text file.  If you use it, it somehow renders the directory the file itself is located unmovable.  For example-

```
cuLocation = "C:\\Users\\WoopyCat\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\currentUser.txt";
System.IO.StreamReader objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(cuLocation);
currentUser = objReader.ReadLine();
TBcurrentUser.Text = "The current user is " + currentUser + ".";
```

All this happens upon form load.  Then I have a button click event set up where this happens-

```
System.IO.Directory.Move("C:\\Users\\WoopyCat\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft", "C:\\Users\\WoopyCat\\AppData\\Roaming\\.MCSwitcher\\" + currentUser);
```

However, the IDE says access to .minecraft is denied.  But if I remove this code-

```
cuLocation = "C:\\Users\\WoopyCat\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\currentUser.txt";
System.IO.StreamReader objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(cuLocation);
currentUser = objReader.ReadLine();
```

And replace it with this code-

```
currentUser = "Paul";
```

It works perfectly.  It can access .minecraft.  But I need to read the currentUser.txt file in order for my program to work.  Any help?

Again, to reiterate- this code-

```
cuLocation = "C:\\Users\\WoopyCat\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\currentUser.txt";
System.IO.StreamReader objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(cuLocation);
currentUser = objReader.ReadLine();
```

Prevents this code from working-

```
 System.IO.Directory.Move("C:\\Users\\WoopyCat\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft", "C:\\Users\\WoopyCat\\AppData\\Roaming\\.MCSwitcher\\" + currentUser);
```

Comment: Please don't put tag information in your title. The tagging system here is very good at classifying things, and doesn't need help. :-) Please see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661). Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just really eager to fix this error and fix my program.  Thanks for the tip.  :)

Comment: The error message you posted does not have a slash between `Roaming` and `.minecraft`. Is that a copy-paste error?

Comment: Yes, it was a copy/paste error.

Comment: If it was a copy/paste error, [edit] to fix it so your question is clear.

Comment: Are you still logged in to the `WoopyCat` account while you try and run the program or are you running this as a different user? Open a command prompt window and run `whoami` and let us know what it says.

Comment: Yep, still logged as WoopyCat.  Also, would it make a difference if some code was copy/pasted from my previous program?

Comment: Did you try in some other drive ?

Comment: How do you mean?  I need that specific folder to be moved, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do close obj.Reader before the move using objReader.Close() , right? Having a stream opened to the file will prevent it being moved. If that isnt the case, theres an application (handle I think it's called) that will let you see what has access to a file, so you can see whats preventing you from moving the dir.

Comment: Great! I'm not sure on vb, but in c# you can use whats called a using statement 'using(var stream=new StreamReader(path) {[code using reader here] }', which will automatically dispose the stream outside of its scope, id recommend seeing if theres a vb equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible reason I can think of is you are not really the WoopyCat user, here is the correct way to get the path based of the currently running user.

```
var roamingFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData); //This equals the \AppData\Roaming\ folder for the current user
Directory.Move(Path.Combine(roamingFolder, ".minecraft"), Path.Combine(roamingFolder,currentUser));
```

Comment: Have you tried manually moving the folder??? Might be some issue with the ACL on the folder. Check it using the Security tab in the folder properties...

Comment: Yea, If you could open the security tab and post a screenshot, maybe that might shed some light on it. I use Minecraft too and I ran that exact code to change my folder from `.minecraft` to `.minecraft2` and back again and it worked fine. Something is screwed up on the security settings of your Minecraft folder.

Comment: do you have the folder opened in windows explorer? If not try to reboot your system, it will close it if it's opened by another process.

Comment: @Prospector Explorer is not the problem, I had my minecraft folder open too and it happily renamed it to `.minecraft2` while I had the folder open.

Comment: Here's something else weird- when I create a new project and move the file once the form loads, it works!  But then once I code the rest of my program, it fails.

Comment: Are you generating the `.minecraft` folder via your code or is the launcher creating it? If you are creating it, perhaps there is a mistake in your code that is messing with the ACL's.

Comment: It's generated, so that's why it cannot be accessed by the other program!  That's it!  Now how do I fix it?

Comment: The image I really cared about was WoopyCat's permisions. On how to fix it, you will need to update your original question and include the code where you create the folder.

Comment: The folder was created in my other program.

Comment: System.IO.Directory.Move("C:\\Users\\WoopyCat\\AppData\\Roaming\\" + each2, "C:\\Users\\WoopyCat\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft");              This was how it was created.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33430/discussion-between-theunrealmegashark-and-scott-chamberlain)